# jQuery code not showing up

Tags: jquery, html

I don't have much experience with jQuery but am trying to implement an image slider for my website. I read the instructions for it and I believe I implemented it properly but when I navigate to the page to test it, there's just nothing there. Even if the jQuery doesn't work, shouldn't the div be showing up, at least? I don't understand what's going wrong. Can someone please see my code and let me know if there's any mistake? I am not including the surrounding code because I have several external stylesheets which would be a pain to copy/paste. However, if it is necessary, I will tackle that later.

```
 <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="ion/js/ion-imageSlider/ion.imageSlider.js"></script>
 <script>
 $("#mySlider").ionImageSlider();
 </script>
 <div class="ion-image-slider" id="mySlider">
 <a href="http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4102/4911060184_6f78a83288.jpg"><img src="http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4102/4911060184_6f78a83288.jpg" data-caption="Shakespeare House" /></a>
 <a href="http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4096/4925016771_3bac794a81.jpg"><img src="http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4096/4925016771_3bac794a81.jpg" data-caption="Old site" /></a>
 <a href="http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4119/4911067626_a52a6ca492.jpg"><img src="http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4119/4911067626_a52a6ca492.jpg" data-caption="Gymga" /></a>
 </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to access an element that is not yet added to `DOM` Use [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to ensure that elements is added to DOM before you access it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#mySlider").ionImageSlider();
});
```

> While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a
>   page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets
>   such as images have been completely received. In most cases, the
>   script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully
>   constructed. The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be
>   executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to
>   attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code. When using
>   scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties, it's important
>   to reference external stylesheets or embed style elements before
>   referencing the scripts, [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: I added this but it's still not showing up... I'm putting these inline, btw, is this not correct? I know some people place them in the header but this has drawbacks, as well.

Comment: Just tested it out by taking out the jQuery code and it still didn't show up. I then removed the class from the div and then the images showed up but obviously they were not formatted as they needed to be. I have referenced the stylesheet in the header section of the code so I'm not sure why it's not showing up. But it apparently is not the jQuery that's the problem...